# Is it grammatically correct to say "I invited him to join others and I for basketball practice."

Tags: grammar

Or would the correct sentence be:

> I invited him to join I and others for basketball practice.

or

> I invited him to join myself and others for basketball practice.

Comment: Using "me" incorrectly happens naturally, but generally using "I" when you should have used "me" is a conscious (but failed) attempt at being correct (this is called "hypercorrectness").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One correct form would be, **"I invited him to join *me* and others for basketball practice,"** where "me and others" is the object of the the verb "to join." As in, "I invited him to join **us**," (**not "we."**)

Answer (score 1):

Neither "I" or "myself" are correct as the object of 'join' here - the only correct form is only one that would be correct without the "and others" - i.e. "me".
BTW, I can't think of any reason that 'others and me' is grammatically incorrect, but it sounds wrong, I suppose because the nature of 'others' needs something to refer to that's already been established. If it were "*the* others and me" it'd be OK, as it assumes that who "the others" is has been previously established.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be able to say "I invited him to join others and I". If you break down this sentence, into two parts, they would read "I invited him to join others" and "I invited him to join I," which is incorrect. You would need to use "I invited him to join me and others" or "I invited him to join me and the others" instead.